# All Session Variables are removed

Tags: session, iis, webforms, forms-authentication, .net-4.6

We are having a problem with regards to All Session Variables being deleted at random times.
This happens without calling Session.Abort(); or Session.Clear(); IIS is also not recycled and NO App_Code, Bin, Global.asax or Web.config changes are made when this happens. We have enabled logs on iis to confirm app pool is not being recycled. IIS is also set to recycle once a day in the morning and no limits are set on iis to force recycle

This happens very randomly and not able to reproduce at all. We use Formsauthentication, but the site determines if it should be redirected back to the login page by looking if 2 critical session variables exists(sometimes the sessions are cleared even while authenticated aswell. We use default In-Proc session State.
We have tried response.redirect(...,false) when setting variables without any luck. This happens on a single server.

We are somehow running a web farm(Login screen handles the load and redirects to a server, but user stays on that server, until he logs out).

Any help in the correct direction will be appreciated!

Comment: What i can add to this, at times this only happens to 1 user and other times everybody connected to the site - added code to determine this

Comment: For the case when only one user is affected, it sound like the user's Session simply times out due to inactivity. For cases where all users are affected, it really does sound like the application gets restarted... About the web farm, how is the user kept on the same server? By cookie or IP or some other way? If by IP, he can possibly move to a different server if he switches from wired to wireless network... Or by switching from 3G to Wifi on a phone.